# Como puedo meter un if de php dentro de código de script

Tags: javascript, php

Necesito realizar una condición de tal manera que diga que si es de tipo administrador me ponga los botones de visualizar, eliminar y editar, de otro modo solo me agregue el botón de visualizar.

```
{
                "data": "telefono_director"
            },
            {
                "data": "cedulaprofesional_director"
            },
            {
                data: null,
                "defaultContent": `<button class='consulta btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleDirectivo' title="Ver Detalles"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                <button class='editar btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalActualizarDirectivo' title="Editar Datos"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                <button class='eliminar btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEliminarDirectivo' title="Eliminar Registro"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>`
            }
```

Intente agregarlo de esta manera pero me sale error

```
{
                "data": "telefono_director"
            },
            {
                "data": "cedulaprofesional_director"
            },
            {
                data: null,
                <?php if ($tipo == 'administrador') {
                "defaultContent": `<button class='consulta btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleDirectivo' title="Ver Detalles"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                <button class='editar btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalActualizarDirectivo' title="Editar Datos"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                <button class='eliminar btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEliminarDirectivo' title="Eliminar Registro"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>`
                php } ?>
            }
```

Comment: Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente y PHP trabaja del lado del servidor. Te aconsejo que no mezcles nunca los contextos. Eso no quita que, desde el servidor (PHP) puedes construir contenido para mostrarlo en el cliente (Javascript / HTML), en ese caso, en la misma lógica que genera el contenido que mostrarás en el cliente, construye los botones según la condición deseada. Y, cuando quieras intercambiar datos dinámicos entre cliente y servidor usa Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

Comment: ¿y que error te sale?  Por que eso que muestras... ¿que es?  ¿un archivo php donde estás generando una salida en javascript? ¿o bien un archivo js que intentas que interprete PHP?  Danos un poco más de contexto para ayudarte mejor, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una forma de como poder mostrar u ocultar un contenido o una porcion de contenido (html) en el DOM con javascript.

no se si el `array` esta en el propio javascript o estas usando `.json`; pero no hay mucha diferencia.

Primero recorro el `array` con `forEach` y luego ahi se declara con `if` lo que hay que hacer.

En la condicional `if` se declara que hacer o que mostrar cualquier cosa. Aqui se muestra entre backticks ``` `` ``` el contenido del `array`.

Luego se guarda en una variable, y luego se muestra en el DOM.

```js
let tipo = [
{
    data: "telefono_director",
    data2: "cedulaprofesional_director",
    defaultContent: "<button class='consulta btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleDirectivo' title='Ver Detalles'>Ver</button>",
    defaultDos: "<button class='editar btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalActualizarDirectivo' title='Editar Datos'>Editar</button>",
    defaultTres: "<button class='eliminar btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEliminarDirectivo' title='Eliminar Registro'>Eliminar</button>"
}
];

// Se guarda en esta variable
let tipoGuardado = [];

// Se recorre la lista array
tipo.forEach( (item) => {

// true es solo para ver en este ejemplo
if (true) { // Default
    tipoGuardado += `
        ${item.defaultContent}
    `;
}

else if ($tipo == 'administrador') { // Administrador
    tipoGuardado += `
        ${item.defaultContent} ${item.defaultDos} ${item.defaultTres}
    `;
}

});

// Aqui se muestra el contenido 
document.querySelector(".datos").innerHTML = tipoGuardado;
```

```html
<div class="datos"></div>
```

Leva en cuenta que no se mezcla PHP con Javascript. PHP se mezcla con HTML (o viceversa).
Javascript incluye HTML.